# Android studio, Google Maps: V2 maps not fully loaded

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Me and my team have a problem on google maps in Android Studio. The maps showed is able to zooming up to a certain point. After maps remains pixelated (zooming up maps does not loading). We have tested in many devices, in a tablet for example some maps regions are not exactly showed: there are many gray squares.
The same code for the maps that working in another project, imported in our project has this strange behavior (We have tested both in wifi and cellular data network).
We are followed step by step google develeoper guide.
We have this **configuration**:
android studio 1.1.0
min sdk 16
target sdk 21

**Gradle conf**:
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'

This is a screenshot of my situation: http://oi59.tinypic.com/vra3o2.jpg

Comment: did you try to clean the application data? Maybe you changed the key or switched from debug to release (or vice versa) and have some problems on that?

Are you working on custom tiles in the app?

Comment: I have already done your suggestions. I haven't changed the key and in google developer console. Further my key is accept from any android applications (I haven't used sha1 ecc.).

Comment: I can't get the last sentence you say, but I think you know how to check and validate a key basing on your keystore (you can't copy the same key from one application to the other, you have to set package and SHA1 on the console for that new application.

Comment: I did this test, generating the keystore, but I always have this problem. In another project in Android study using the same key (allowed all using sha1 etc.) Map works well.

Comment: I repeat to you my trials: in a new project with the same key, the maps works very well; while in my main project maps has this zoom problem.

Comment: non so se sia regolare scrivere in ita

Non so il discorso della chiave "a tutti" senza sha1 (mai usato e non so come funzioni),io generalmente prendo package dell'app(occhio a build.gradle se cambia package!) e il/gli sha1 dei compon del team,poi genero una chiave unica per tutti (1per riga) e la cosa funziona.
In caso di problemi faccio come sopra,cancello i dati dell'app ed avvio.Controlla in console se ti da errori sulla key!

I don't know about "everyone" sha1 key (never used), but i generally take package,sha1 of team comp. and gen 1 key for all.
If issues,I delete app data and restart.

Comment: Sorry for multi posting, took too much time to write, anyway it is very strange. From the screenshot it seems it is on a new project that does basically nothing, so it should not be your code problem. If you zoom out completely and try to zoom in the bad area, do you see again the issue? Do you see issue in logcat?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In logcat it's all ok.

Comment: Now I'm trying to fix build gradle based on your suggestions.

Comment: I've verified gradle but maps is wrong! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved. The problem was in gradle. I'm using aviary and its dependecy from okhttp blocked google maps loading.
This are line added under dependencies:
    compile('com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0') {
        **exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp"**
    }

...
    **compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'**